# Is it true that there are infinitely many square numbers of the form $\lfloor n\sqrt{2}\rfloor$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, continued-fractions

Is it true that there are infinitely many square numbers in the sequence $\left \lfloor n \sqrt{2} \right \rfloor $ with $n$ is a whole number? If not, how can we prove it?

Comment: "infinitely many" you probably mean.

Comment: Look into [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) expansions for $\sqrt{2}$, e.g.

Comment: Nice suggestion. I have adjusted the title and the tags.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Interesting question. [Beatty sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence) give that every positive natural number is either of the form $\lfloor \sqrt{2}\,a\rfloor$ or of the form $\lfloor (2+\sqrt{2})\,b\rfloor$, for some $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$. If we assume that only a finite number of squares belong to the first sequence, we have that every large enough square is of the form $\lfloor (2+\sqrt{2})\,b\rfloor$ for some $b\in\mathbb{N}$. Now we may use the general properties of continued fractions to derive a contradiction. We have that
$$ \sqrt{2}=[1;2,2,2,2,\ldots] $$
and if $\left\{\frac{p_k}{q_k}\right\}$ is the sequence of convergents of such continued fraction,
$$ q_k^2 \sqrt{2}-p_k q_k = \frac{(-1)^k}{2\sqrt{2}}+o(1) $$
as $k\to +\infty$. Similarly,
$$ \frac{1}{2+\sqrt{2}}=[0;3,2,2,2,\ldots] $$
and if $\left\{\frac{p_k}{q_k}\right\}$ is the sequence of convergents of such continued fraction,
$$ \frac{q_k^2}{2+\sqrt{2}}-p_k q_k = \frac{(-1)^k}{2\sqrt{2}}+o(1) $$
as $k\to +\infty$. Assuming that $q_k^2$ belongs to the complementary Beatty sequence we get
$$ b \leq \frac{q_k^2}{2+\sqrt{2}} \leq b+\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{2}},\qquad b\in\mathbb{N} $$
which contradicts the previous statement if $k$ is large and *odd*.

The same argument works also by switching the roles of the original Beatty sequence and its complementary sequence. In particular we have that

> There are infinite squares of the form $\lfloor \sqrt{2}\,a\rfloor$
>   and infinite squares of the form $\lfloor
>  \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)\,b\rfloor$. Every non-zero square is represented by exactly one of such forms.

A more advanced approach is proving that the set $\{\lfloor n\sqrt{2}\rfloor:n\geq 0\}$ contains a difference set $S-S$ where $S\subset\mathbb{N}$ has a positive density. Indeed, by the [Furstenberg-Sárközy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furstenberg%E2%80%93S%C3%A1rk%C3%B6zy_theorem) there are infinite squares in any difference set of the previous form. This is the quantitative version of the fact that the squares form a [Heilbronn set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heilbronn_set), i.e. a neighbourhood of zero in the Bohr topology.

The first positive squares of the form $\lfloor \sqrt{2}\,a\rfloor$ are $$1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 289, 400.$$
The first positive squares of the complementary form $\lfloor \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)\,b\rfloor$ are
$$64, 81, 225, 256, 324, 361, 484, 529.$$

Comment: As usual, very nice. Any explicit form for the squares?