# Minkowski difference in a pseudo-AP

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, fourier-analysis, diophantine-approximation, infinitary-combinatorics

This question arises from a previous [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2955689/44121) of mine, in which I claimed a fact I am not so sure about.

Let $\alpha\in(1,2)$ be an irrational number (feel free to assume $\alpha=\sqrt{2}$ or $\alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ if you are more comfortable with periodic continued fractions) and let $E$ be the set of numbers of the form $\lfloor n\alpha\rfloor$ with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

**Claim**: there exists $F\subset\mathbb{Z}$ *with positive [lower asymptotic density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density)* such that the set $F-F$ (Minkowski difference) is entirely contained in $E$.

I thought it was enough to exploit the fact that the discrete Fourier transform of $\mathbb{1}_E$ is well-behaved (so [Szemerédi's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di%27s_theorem) applies, for instance), but I am having troubles in actually achieving a positive density for $F$. Maybe I am regarding this the wrong way, and it is enough to remove few elements from $E$ and get $\overline{E}$ such that $\overline{E}-\overline{E}\subset E$, in a purely combinatorial fashion. Any help?

Comment: This might be obvious, but helpful too: since any difference set is symmetric with respect to $0$, if such $F$ actually exists then $F-F$ is a subset of $E'=E\cap(-E)$. If $\alpha=\sqrt{2}$, the difference between consecutive elements of $E'$ is either $1$ or $3$.

Comment: i have no idea what "i thought it was enough to exploit the fact that the discrete fourier transform of $1_E$ is well-behaved (so Szemeredi's theorem applies, for instance)" means. i don't see (1) how the niceness fourier transform of 1_E would allow one to use szemeredi's theorem nor (2) how the use of Szemeredi's theorem would give an infinite F (even without positive density), or just how Szemeredi's theorem is at all relevant